# $f:[0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and positive such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and positive such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx=1$ for each $x \in [0,1]$ prove that there is a unique $g(x) \in[1,2]$ such that $\int_{x}^{g(x)} f(t) dt=1$ prove that the function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the class $\mathbb{C}^1$

by the fundamental theorem of calculus $F(1)-F(0)= \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: Choose $f$ as above, with $$\int_{1/2}^1f=\int_1^2f=1/3.$$Then $$\int_{x}^{g(x)}f\le2/3 $$for every $x\in[1/2,1]$.

Comment: Just curious, why can't you simply delete your answer? My answers all have a "delete" option right next to the "edit" option. (In fact, I did post and then delete an answer here.) Does your answer not show that option?

Comment: @BarryCipra If I only wanted to delete this answer I could. I've been informed by the moderators that my posts do nothing but add noise to the site. I don't want to do that, so I'm trying to erase my presence on my way out. Turns out you can only delete five posts per day. Sorry to have inflicted all this crap on you.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know there was a per diem limit on deletes. But I'm not sure editing does much to erase one's presence, since anyone, I think, can see the complete edit history if they desire.

Answer (score 1):

My comment was getting too big, so this is not an answer, but a request to rewrite your question:

Your question doesn't really make sense. For example, let

$f(x) = 1$ for $0\le x \le 1$ and $f(x)=2-x$ for $1 \le x \le \frac{3}{2}$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $\frac{3}{2} \le x \le 2$

Now let $x=\frac{9}{10}$. You cannot find a point $g(x) \in [1,2]$ such that the integral in question is 1.

Comment: Nice counter example. $g(x)$ would need to be $29/10$.

Comment: Well, $f$ isn't even defined at $\frac{29}{10}$ :).